# splitting WMA files

Tags: audio

Is there any small simple tool can split WMA files into equal size piece? I'd like to split a 2hour file into 5min a piece.

Also, if it also support mp3 and other format, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found 'MP3 WMA cutter'!

Answer (score 1):

**[poc-streamer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/poc-streamer)** works fine on mp3 files.